# CSS3 Shape Issue - Blend Mode Multiply

Tags: css, blend, css-shapes

I am trying to...

1) Make my CSS3 shapes have some 'multiply' blend mode &

2) Stretch the entire shape area the full size of the web page.

Is it possible to stretch this area 100% width & height of the web page AND make the whole area transparent so some yellow comes through?

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; 
            width: 0; 
            height: 0; 
            border: 100px solid #1F80AF; 
            border-left-color: #0099CC; 
            border-right-color: #0099CC;"></div>
```

I have a **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/485vb/)**.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: not too sure of what you look for. You could draw the shape via background with rgba() colors. like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/485vb/3/

Comment: @GCyrillus this is an excellent comment! I will try this in my solution and see how I go - many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="absolute">
        Some content yo!
    </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
    html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background:url(http://placehold.it/250) repeat 0 0;
}

div.wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -mox-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-top:rgba(25,25,255,0.8) solid 50vh; /* Nothing below IE8 or Firefox 19 */
    border-bottom:rgba(25,25,255,0.8) solid 50vh; /* Nothing below IE8 or Firefox 19 */
    border-left: rgba(0,0,255,0.5) solid 50vw;; 
    border-right: rgba(0,0,255,0.5) solid 50vw;;
    -moz-background-clip: content;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
      -webkit-background-clip: content;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
          background-clip: content-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
}

div.absolute {
    position:absolute;
    left:-50vw;
    top:-50vh;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/485vb/4/

So, basically what this does is uses the `background-clip` property to say, "keep the content opaque, everything outside can be transparent."

Then we use `vw` and `vh` or viewport units to set the left and right borders to just under 50% of the viewport-width (`vw`) and set the top and bottom just under 50% of the viewport-height (`vh`).

This should get you close to what you want to do.

**EDIT**
GCyrillus comment is really good solution, too.

**EDIT 2**
Updated to include positioned content.

Comment: Wow - I think we're almost there!!! Out of interest, if I wanted to place content on the overlay, how would I do this?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk use absolute positionning :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Well, that was easy!! Thank you!! :-)